# How to use the PARAMETER_VALUE ObjCode in AtTask API

Tags: attask

In the sample code there's an ObjCode that I cannot find in the documentation on the AtTask developer site:

public static readonly ObjCode PARAMETER_VALUE      = new ObjCode("pval");

I did see where it says - "The following is a list of Secondary Objects; meaning, they can only be accessed through one of the other objects. There is no top level service." and Parameter Value is listed. So how does one retrieve the data for this ObjCode? There's no relationship to any other set of data that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter Values are the custom form data elements that are attached to the object and that have an actual value. It will not display null fields. Anything that can have a custom form can have parameterValues

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't answer the question. The typical usage of an ObjCode is:

string json = client.GetRequest(@"https://<domain>.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/ctgy/search?&ID=" + formID + "&sessionID=" + SessionID + "&ID_Mod=eq&fields=categoryParameters:*");

where "ctgy" is the ObjCode. However, this doesn't work for the PARAMETER_VALUE ObjCode. One would assume it's used to get the values for the CategoryParameters for a Category, but that assumption is either false or undocumented from what I can see. How do I get the actual values for custom form fields?

Comment: Is this some coincidence @Brad Littler https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/222659667-Tracking-Hour-records-with-the-API

Answer (score 0):

Parameter values will show you the values entered for custom data on an object proper usage is

```
attask/api-unsupported/proj/54945768005a361d7999f86e2d65a3e4?fields=parameterValues
```

this will show all the value entered for the custom data on this project. 
this will return something like this

```
{
    data: {
        ID: "54945768005a361d7999f86e2d65a3e4",
        name: "TEST PARAMETER VALUE PROJECT",
        objCode: "PROJ",
        parameterValues: {
            DE:Parameter value 2: "Entered value 2",
            DE:Param value 1: "Entered value 1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that before. Doesn't seem to be the answer:

{"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"APIModel V4_0 does not support field parameterOptions (Category)"}}

Comment: I get results back when I hit the param objCode, but that doesn't give me data entered by the user, just the options for that parameter.

Comment: This is because you are making the call at the category level not the Parameter level. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Making the call at the parameter level just retrieves the options for the parameters. I'm trying to retrieve the data that has actually been entered by the user into the custom form, as I said in my previous comment.